# about using "a" or "the" before the feeling noun "content"

Tags: uncountable-nouns

This question is about whether using **a** or **the** is possible or not in front of a noun that means a feeling, which, in this post's case, is **content**(satisfaction).

The sentence below is from the entry [for **content(noun meaning satisfaction)** in Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/content2_3).

> She stood for a moment looking with **content** at her husband.

And I am just wondering if there can be any case where having **a** or **the** inserted before **content** like below is allowed.

> She stood for a moment looking with **a/the content** at her husband.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It would only be appropriate when the article is serving its purpose as an article. For example:

> She looked at him with rage; the rage she looked at him with was
>   fiery.

Your sentence "looking with a/the content at her husband" would not be correct.

Another situation where articles could be used is a metaphor like

> She looked at him with a warm gaze of content.

or

> She looked at him with the warmest gaze of content in the world.

or even

> She looked at him with the content of a million suns.
>
> She looked at him with a content so warm that it could be physically felt.

Hopefully those last examples answer your question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, SUM1. I appreciate all the examples and cases you wrote. And as for the last examples, should I regard them as in the way the phrase ***a love of learning*** serves? The noun **love** is a noun generally uncountable, whose meaning is associated with a kind of feeling or emotion just like **content** is. And what is common between **content** and **love** in those examples is that the nouns are described by additional phrases. Is my understanding correct? :)

Comment: I would say yes, that's the general rule. Of course, different uncountable nouns work with different additional phrases. You couldn't replace "love" in your phrase with "rage" or "content", but you could replace the nouns in my examples with "love". :)

Comment: Thank you, SUM1. But if I may ask you more, what I wanted to say in the above comment was not just that the nouns are described by the additional phrases but that they are treated as countable with an article **a** or **the** used before them. So I wanted to ask you whether it is the additional description of the noun that makes the normally-uncountable nouns work as a countable noun in those particular cases. If you reply to and confirm this question, it would be greatly helpful and appreciated.